# Windows Phone 7 WCF CallBack PollingDuplex Binding Error

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I am using WCF in Windows Phone 7 project. I want CallBack Services of WCF in my Project. But, I got an error while using wsDualHttpBinding in the project. So, I googled about it a lot. So, the conclusion after me is to use PollingHttpBinding with the Windows phone Application. So, I resume my work with the PollingDuplex. I used the PollingDuplex reference in the Server side WCF Service from the path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Server\System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex.dll". and it works well and also able to consume the service through SLSVCUTIL.EXE. But when I tries to include the PollingDuplex ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Client\System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex.dll") reference to my Windows Phone 7 Client side code, then it gives the following error while adding the reference:

"Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.ServiceModel.Extensions, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

Please help me in resolving this error.

System Specifications:

Windows 8 ( 64 Bit )
Visual Studio 2012
Windows Phone 8 SDK
Silverlight 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is Duplex dll you are referencing wasn't built for Windows Phone or by using Windows Phone compatible assemblies...so one would need those dlls to be rebuilt from scratch using WP assemblies...I had simmilar problems trying to reference some assemblies in Windows Phone 7 that were made for desktop silverlight instead back when augmented reality wasn't supported and people used desktop Silverlight Augmented Reality project (SLAR)...eventually there was a solution but it was cumbersome.
If you were able to solve this I'd really like to know how please? Is PollingDuplex supported at all on Windows Phone? If not are there any alternatives working with the same WCF server binding?